# Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard on activity state onStop

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method

I have an `EditText` and a `Button` in my layout. After writing in the edit field and click this button to  `go back my fragment`, I want to hide the virtual keyboard. I assume that there's a simple, but i tried some way and it not work:

That code show how the `Button` work:

```
private void onButtonClicked(){
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

That code for some solution but that can't help.
This code i using `hideSoftInputFromWindow` but when i call 'EditText.getWindowToken()', it not hide the soft keyboard (I also change the 0 value to InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY or InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS and it not work):

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);  
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(
      Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(myEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

With this code, in another screen of this app, it work. This screen is an activity so i think that problem is fragment's problem.

My fragment code:

```
public class ChangeEmailFragment extends BaseFragment {
    private TextView mTxtCurrentEmail;
    private EditText mEdtNewEmail;
    private EditText mEdtPassword;
    private TextView mTxtSubmit;

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing())
            dialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_email, container,
                false);
        mTxtCurrentEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_email);
        mEdtNewEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
        mEdtPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
        mTxtSubmit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button_submmit);
        return view;
    }

    private void showErrorDialog(String msg) {
        Builder builder = new Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.fg_change_email_dialog_error_title));
        builder.setMessage(msg);
        builder.setNegativeButton(getText(R.string.common_ok), null);
        dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

My activity code:

```
@Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEdtUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

Comment: Post your `Fragment` code

Comment: That is my fragment code  
`public static ChangeEmailFragment newInstance() {
  ChangeEmailFragment changeEmailFragment = new ChangeEmailFragment();
  return changeEmailFragment;
 }`  

Because it too long so i will post that at the next comment

Comment: `@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_email, container,
    false);
  mTxtCurrentEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.current_email);
  mEdtNewEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
  mEdtPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
  mTxtSubmit = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.button_submmit);
  return view;
 }`

Comment: @NWD post your all code in your Question. What is this?

Comment: I used the suggest that is `code` but i can't post my formated code. So, please teach me how. Great thank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this way in `Fragment`

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Comment: That work for me. Thank you! So i understand that when my cursor place at fragment, i must call `hideSoftInputFromWindow` in my fragment but not activity. Is that right?

Comment: @Nin_in_the_winD ya exactly.