# Hide soft keyboard in android when app is force-stopped

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard

When I force-stop my app via adb while keyboard is visible, it stays visible.

I did the same test with Google Chrome app and keyboard gets hidden there.

I know how to hide keyboard when activity is put into background ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24009037/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard-on-activity-state-onstop)), but it seems that I cannot intercept when my app is force-stopped ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21040339/how-to-know-when-my-app-has-been-killed)).

Is there some simple solution to my problem? Thanks.

Comment: You can write the method to remove keyboard inside `onTaskRemoved()` of the `Service` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably solve this with a service.

Take a look at this answer which is related to your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33078782/2664634